# To check differentiability of multivariable function at origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus

To check function is differentiable or not

$$f(x,y) = \left\lbrace\begin{array}{cr}
          \frac{xy}{|x|} ,& x \neq 0\\
           0  ,  & x=0
\end{array}\right.
$$
I think due to modulus function f is not differentiable. But i am not sure

Thanks

Comment: Differentiable where?

Comment: @GoodDeeds at origin

Comment: Have you checked continuity of partial derivatives? Suppose they are continuous then you can say it is differentiable at $0$

Comment: Look at $x \mapsto f(x,1)$. Is this continuous? Can $f$ be differentiable?

Comment: @copper.hat no f cannot be differentiable. am i right ?

Comment: @TaylorTed: If a function is differentiable at a point then it is continuous there. So if it is not continuous at a point, it cannot be differentiable there.

Comment: @copper.hat So what is answer

Comment: @copper.hat f is continuous at origin but is it differentiable.please let me know

Comment: Sorry, my comments were misleading, I missed the origin part.

Comment: @copper.hat just tell me if it is differentiable at origin and i will think proof

Comment: @copper.hat then my textbook is wrong

Comment: Just plot the function (with Google or Wolfram Alpha, or whatever). Does it *look* like the graph has a tangent plane at the origin...?

Comment: @HansLundmark i plotted graph but how to check(from graph) whether it has tangent plane at origin.

Comment: I don't want to sound unhelpful, but that should be pretty obvious, I think...

Comment: @HansLundmark i have never studies differentiability geometrically. Just tell me what is answer as per you

Comment: What? To me, that sounds completely bizarre! How on earth...? But well, whatever makes you happy. Then you just have to go for the algebraic approach: determine $f'_x(0,0)$ and $f'_y(0,0)$ to begin with (using the definition of partial derivative), then investigate the limit that's in the definition of differentiability, and the answer should present itself to you. But I find it *much* easier to just look at the graph.

Answer (score 3):

One way of checking is to look at the directional derivative, 
$df(x,h) = \lim_{t \to 0} {f(x+th)-f(x) \over t}$. If the function is
differentiable, we have $df(x,h) = Df(x)h$, where $Df(x)$ is the
derivative.

Then $df((0,0),(1,1)) = \lim_{t \to 0} { t^2 \over |t|t}= \lim_{t \to 0} \operatorname{sgn} (t) $, however this limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The function is not differential along x direction at (0, y) where $y \ne 0$. $f(x, y) = y$ for x > 0, $y \ne 0$, and $f(x, y) = -y$ for $x < 0)$ f is discontinuos at (0, y) where $y \ne 0$

Comment: The question (according to the title) concerned differentiability at the *origin*, and then this is not relevant.